# Open ID Implementation on Play Framework

Tags: authentication, playframework, openid, openid-provider

I'd like to have my own Open ID server for authentication so that different apps use the same user database. I'm using Play Framework. Is there any library for this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any OpenId Provider library for Play Framework. But you can find openId client library for Play at https://github.com/pac4j/play-pac4j